# Explanation about the HTTP_Q_UA key on the $_SERVER array

Tags: php

A few days ago I found an error generated by a visitor surfing my website. I am used to store in the error log all [$_SERVER] and [$_SESSION] arrays linked to the visitor. Among other info coming from the visitor, I found the he was surfing from China using Win XP OS and Firefox Browser. The content of the 'HTTP_Q_UA' element in the [$_SERVER] array was: "KQB22_GA/220020&KMTT_3/200020&JV2&151920&SunMicrosystemswtk&0&4309&V3".
I would like to know what is the purpose of the key `'HTTP_Q_UA'` on the `$_SERVER` array.
What are the possible values and what does it describe?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Where does this value come from? how was this value generated? Give us some info. on to your question

Comment: `HTTP_Q_UA`.... typical value  `*QB*29_GA/11*00*&K*MT*_3/22*00*&J*2&*52*19&Ma*iE*00&10*1&*97*&V*`.... user agent `OneBrowser/3.1 (MauiE800)`

Comment: @Martin A few days ago I found an error generated by a visitor surfing my website. I am used to store in the error log all [$_SERVER] and [$_SESSION] arrays linked to the visitor. Among other info coming from the visitor, I found the he was surfing from China using Win XP OS and Firefox Browser. The content of the 'HTTP_Q_UA' element in the [$_SERVER] array was: "KQB22_GA/220020&KMTT_3/200020&JV2&151920&SunMicrosystemswtk&0&4309&V3".

Comment: ok now take everything you just wrote and **edit** your question putting your details into the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Q-UA` HTTP header is [sent by the QQ browser](https://citizenlab.org/2016/03/privacy-security-issues-qq-browser/). Its exact structure doesn't seem to be described anywhere public.